# Proteger ruta "login" despues de haber auntentificado - Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue3, vue-router

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

Utilizo el beforeEach para proteger mis rutas:

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
  const rutaIsProtected = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.rutaProtegida)
  if(rutaIsProtected && store.state.token === null){
    next('/login')
  }else{
    next()    
  }
})
```

Me funciona correctamente para poder redirigir al login cuando no hay token.
Lo que necesito es como hacer que el usuario ya no vuelva acceder a ***Login*** mientras este autentificado. Ya que si da **atras** en el navegador, lo devuelve a **login** o si digita la ruta en la barra de derecciones, lo lleva a **login**.

Answer (score 1):

```
router.beforeEach((to,from,next) => {
  const rutaIsProtected = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.rutaProtegida)
  if(rutaIsProtected && store.state.token === null {
    next('/login')
  }else if(!rutaIsProtected && !!store.state.token){
    next('/dashboard') //o cualquier ruta donde quieras que vuelva
  }else{
    next()
  }
})
```

Es básicamente agregar otra condición donde checas si la ruta no está protegida y el token existe, entonces re diriges a otro lugar

Comment: Excelente. Me funcionó. Gracias

Comment: Acepta la respuesta si te fue de utilidad, saludos